# ArgumentParserコンストラクタ引数parentsに、相互排他グループを含む引数グループを渡すと、正しくグループ化されない原因を教えてください。

Tags: python

## 実行環境

- Python 3.9.7
- argparse 1.1

## やりたいこと

以下のように、相互排他グループ（`--foo` or `--bar`）を含む引数グループ"global options"を作成したいです。
引数グループ"global options"は、各コマンドで共通のコマンドライン引数なので、`ArgumentParser`コンストラクタの`parents`引数に設定しました。

```
import argparse


def create_parent_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    argument_group = parser.add_argument_group("global options")
    argument_group.add_argument("--xxx")
    argument_group.add_argument("--yyy")

    exclusive_group = argument_group.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    exclusive_group.add_argument("--foo", action="store_true")
    exclusive_group.add_argument("--bar", action="store_true")
    return parser

def main():
    parent_parser = create_parent_parser()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test", parents=[parent_parser])
    parser.add_argument("--num", type=int, nargs="+")
    args = parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
$ python foo.py -h
usage: foo.py [-h] [--xxx XXX] [--yyy YYY] [--foo | --bar] [--num NUM [NUM ...]]

test

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --foo
  --bar
  --num NUM [NUM ...]

global options:
  --xxx XXX
  --yyy YYY
```

## 質問

相互排他グループ（`--foo` or `--bar`）は、"global options"グループに設定したにも関わらず、"option arguments"グループ内に表示されていました。
なぜ、このように表示されるのでしょうか？
`parents`引数に設定しなければ、`--foo` or `--bar`は、"global options"グループ内に表示されました。

## 補足

発生している現象を、[Qiita](https://qiita.com/yuji38kwmt/items/1d51ca62f6e8fb1b66fc) にもう少し詳しく書きました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[argparse](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/argparse.html)の公式ドキュメントに記載されている通り、現時点では相互排他は引数グループ名のサポートが未対応なのではないでしょうか。

リンク先より抜粋:

> 現在のところ、相互排他引数グループは [add_argument_group()](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument_group) の *title* と *description* 引数をサポートしていません。